# Android wear 2.0 install bug?

Tags: bootloader, bugs, android-wear

I recently updated my Moto 360 2nd generation to Android Wear 2.0. Due to the fact that I didn't get a notification for it, I forced the installation by spamming the green tick saying that there isn't a update available on version 1.5.

After the installation, I set it up and due to the fact that it got quite hot, I went to setting>system then powered it off.

After holding down the power button to turn it back on, it came up with a boot screen screen. It had various options such as normal boot, recovery, and power off. When I selected normal boot or recovery mode, the watch just seemed to turn off.

I managed to boot back into the Android Wear 2.0 operating system by putting the watch on the charging dock with the dock connected to power. The watch turn on normally when connected to power.

Is this a bug? Are there any fixes for this issue. FYI, I did have about 30% battery, I'm not sure if this is the cause, I highly doubt it though.

Any help and suggestions are much appreciated.

Sid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

I wanted to see if the watch would reboot so I selected reboot in settings and it seemed to boot perfectly fine into the Android Wear 2.0 OS.

I then tested to see if the problem was still there so I powered off then turned the watch back on. To my surprise, the watch booted up normally into the OS.

I guess I just had to reboot the watch...

Answer (score 0):

it probably is a bug, try to install the old firmware, then install android 2.0, pheraps it risolve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I used that trick too on my Moto 360 2nd Gen. Man, was I tapping on the check mark over and over again until it finally decided to work. Other than that, I found no problems with the installation.